Issue with 2-Digit BCD Adder-Subtractor Circuit Using 74LS83

This is my design for a 2-digit adder-subtractor BCD circuit. The design performs well with addition, but for subtraction, it calculates 33 - 73 = 60, which is incorrect. Can anyone help me figure out the issue?
I’ve used a 74LS83 IC along with a bunch of XOR gates, AND gates, NOT gates, and a 7-segment display to show the output. The design was implemented using Proteus 8 Professional.

60 is correct modulo 100.

So what do you expect the result to be if it is now incorrect?

@greybeard i do not understand can you explain a  bit more

@Justme it is supposed to be -40

The difference between -40 and 60 is -100. Numbers an integral multiple of a "modulus" m apart are called equivalent, even "equal modulo m". (You can consider 60 the "ten's complement" representation of -40.)

@greybeard Thank you for your explanation, but I don’t think we’ve covered that concept yet.
The purpose of this circuit is to subtract when
=
1
and add when
=
0
. If the result is negative, it is first sent to the complementary part, which applies the ten’s complement. Then, the two numbers are added together.
If the output is positive, the circuit de-complements it using the ten’s complement and displays the result on the 7-segment display. This means the result shown should be the actual number itself, without any modulo operation applied.

@shahd it is -40. But your circuit cannot show it. It shows -40 as 60. Because if you add 40 to -40 or if you add 40 to 60, you get 0. Same way as your car odometer cannot show negative numbers, but if you have zero and subtract one, it goes to 999999.

I notice the inverter at the input of the AND driving the "ten's decomplementer" is driven by m, the one's one by the "internal carry out".

@Justme
but i tried other numbers and here is the results :
1 - 0 = 1 ✅ ||
0 - 0 = 0 ✅ ||
8 - 7 = 1 ✅ ||
22 - 0 = 22 ✅ ||
22 - 1 = 21 ✅ ||
1 - 22 = -81❌ ||
19 - 1 = 18 ✅ ||
0 - 11 = 97❌ ||
0 - 90 = 11❌ ||
0 - 99 = -18❌

@greybeard, yeah, I made this so if the operation is addition, there is no need to decomplement the result as there was no need in the beginning to complement it.

@shahd The results are correct in binary - but you need to tell how you expect them to be shown.

I don't see how your comment explains the difference between ones and tens.

@greybeard thanks a lot!

@Justme thank you very much!

There are many bugs in your circuit, but there is a particular one that's preventing the "tens" output complementer from operating.
First of all, you should show reference designators for all of the parts in your schematic — otherwise, it's very difficult to talk about details.
There's an AND gate in the lower right quadrant that controls whether the "tens" output complementer is activated. Note that its inputs are the true and complemented versions of the same signal. Therefore, its output will always be false.
